# Mirror shape key with own symmetry axis

Tags: mirror, shape-keys

This one seems a little strange, but I've run into this problem several times while creating shape keys for some objects for motion graphics.

I try to animate an object with shape keys, and I need to create the symmetric one.

[image: shape key 1]
[image: shape key 2]

- I can't use "Mirror Shape key", as it fails because it doesn't have a global X axis symmetry.
- I can't scale it (-1) in the X axis, as it changes the vertex order, and breaks the animation.

My actual solution, is to make a duplicate, scale it (-1) in the X axis, and then move all the vertices in the original mesh with vertex snap into the new position. But it can get quite tedious.

[image: my solution]

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Thanks for editing, David! English is not my main language.